# Why does my code using OpenCv extracts less number of frame from a video

Tags: python, image-processing, video, video-processing

When I used below built-in properties of OpenCv to count number of frame of a video, its shows correct result.

```
video = cv2.VideoCapture(path)
total = int(video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
```

But, when I tried to save all those frames, its store less number of frames. Below is another code for saving frame-

```
def ExtractFrames(self, videoPath):
    srcVideo = cv2.VideoCapture(videoPath)
    try:
        if not os.path.exists('VideoFrames'):
            os.makedirs('VideoFrames')         
    except OSError:
        print('Error: Creating directory.')

    currentframe = 0

    while (True):
        success, image = srcVideo.read()      
        if success:
            fileName = './VideoFrames/frame' + str(currentframe) + '.jpg'
            self.lstVideoFrames.append(fileName)
            cv2.imwrite(fileName, image)
            currentframe += 1  
        else:
            break
```

Comment: Maybe some frames have been corrupted or dropped? In my experience, OpenCV VideoCapture is extremely bad at reporting state and errors. Maybe try exporting all frames with ffmpeg instead.

Comment: Can u give me some hints, how ffmpeg is used in python or is there any method present?

Comment: @Mohiuddin `import os;os.system('ffmpeg -i blablo')` or `import subprocess;proc = subprocess.Popen(['ffmpeg', ...])`